# Plotly Choropleth isn't showing colors using ISO codes

Tags: python, plotly, iso, choropleth

I wish to plot a choropleth of count (frequency) and regions (using regional ISO codes) in US. I'm using plotly currently but I can't seem to figure why the colors which should show frequency isn't been displayed.
I haven't got fibs column, all I've got is ISO.

Thanks..

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType



# with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as # response:
#     counties = json.load(response)

df = location_test.toPandas()

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, locations=df['location_region_iso_code'], color=df['count'],
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 15),
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=3, center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={'count':'Count'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

This is the output I get: [image: Map showing regions and frequency]

Comment: First, you must specify the geojson that has the polygon information and id of the swarm. The data frame associated with it will be colored by referencing the information corresponding to the id.`counties['features'][0]['id']`->'01001'<-df['fips]'

Comment: Probably the current situation is that there is no ISO code in geojson or DF.

Comment: hi @r-beginners i'm trying to plot regions (cities) in US using ISO codes. I havn't got 'fips'

Comment: Simply put, we need ISOcode for both the data frame and geojson.